# c# creating rectangles with different aspect ratios

Tags: c#

I am writing an application in wpf where the user defines a rectangle {x, x, w, h} in a 2d space. That's easy enough. Now the next bit is where I am having difficulty. What this rectangle represents is a picture space and I need to save out two rectangles, one will keep a 1 to 3 aspect ratio while the other maintains a 1 to 4 aspect ratio.

[image]

Now, I've come up with formulas on how to get the aspect ratios (Assuming it's right)

1.3 Aspect Ratio:
w: 2119.0
h: w / 1.3

1.4 Aspect Ratio:
w: h * 1.4
h: 1515.0

But what I don't know is how to i get the coordinates for both. I suspect I have to get it from the initial rectangle's coordinates somehow. But I'm not sure. Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An aspect ratio of 1 to 3 means that the rectangle is three timer higher than it is wide. So calculating the height from the width would simply be `h = 3 * w`.

Comment: @Clemens I made a mistake when said 1 to 3 and 1 to 4. what it is is creating a rectangle with an aspect ratio of 1.3 and another rectangle with an aspect ratio of 1.4.

Comment: Then just use these factors. Given an aspect ratio `a` (e.g. `a = 1.3`), then just calculate `w = a * h` or `h = w / a`. Not sure what your actual problem is with that.

Comment: @Clemens only issue im having is that I don't know how to calculate the positioning (x, y) for the new rectangles.

Comment: The aspect ratio only defines the ratio of width and height. It has nothing to do with the position.

Comment: How would we know your requirements on the position of the rectangles?

Comment: @LarsTech that would be based on the positioning of the main rectangle. Each of the generated rectangles would get the position based on the average position of the main rectangle.

Comment: So the rectangles would be on top of each other?  If so, just get the size different of the length or height and divide by two, and it to the respective X, Y original location.  You should probably post some code.

Comment: @LarsTech haven't done any code on it yet since I'm writing out the formulas first. I'm about to jump on and write the code.

Comment: @LarsTech  so how do I get the size difference of the length and height?

Comment: My guess would be your code would have some rectangle variables.

Comment: @LarsTech yes. the values of the initial rectangle.

Comment: why did I get downvoted? I'm answering every comment to the best of my knowledge. I'm just trying to understand what I need to do, step by step, in order to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that usually in aspect ratio the height is 1 and the width is change according to height and ratio.

- so if you need to chose what will be the height in your case it will
  be like the original: 1515
- the width will be height * 1.3 = 1969.5 and height * 1.4 = 2121
- the x will be x + ((old_width - new_width) / 2), 100 + ((2119 - 1969.5) / 2) = 174.75 and  100 + ((2119 - 2121) / 2) = 99
- the y will be the same or what ever position you want it to be on,
  under or above the original. can be 100 to be on original 1665 to 50 under it and so on.